# How to declare "throws" for `subscript(dynamicMember:)`in @dynamicMemberLookup in swift?

Tags: swift, subscript, throws

When using @dynamicMemberLookup in swift, `subscript` cannot declare a "throws".

```
subscript(dynamicMember member: String) -> Any
```

This is OK.

```
subscript(dynamicMember member: String) throws -> Any
```

This will give a compile error.

Comment: Swift doesn't yet support throwing subscripts or computed properties in general. Here's a relevant thread discussing what the semantics of such declarations would be: https://forums.swift.org/t/clarifying-the-semantics-of-abnormally-terminating-a-storage-access/16244.

Answer (score 8):

Using `throws` in `subscript` is not supported by the language right now. However you can use some tricks to avoid that, meanwhile, keep the feature of `throws`:

```
public subscript(dynamicMember member: String) -> () throws -> Any {
    return { try REAL_FUNCTION_THAT_THROWS()  }
}
```

Just declare the subscription return an block, then add a `()` behind the function to execute the real function. So you could code like this:

```
@dynamicMemberLookup
class A {
    public subscript(dynamicMember member: String) -> () throws -> Any {
         return { try REAL_FUNCTION_THAT_THROWS()  }
    }
}

let a = A()
let value = try? a.doWhatYouWant()
let value2 = try? a.anotherMethod()
```